# Tkinter Dynamically Create and Delete Buttons

Tags: tkinter

I'm trying to dynamically delete the last button and create a new button on the next row via the command function shared by all the "+" button. However, with my current code, I've got nothing but one button staying at the very first row, and it never disappear as I wish and no new buttons appear below it either.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('test1')
root.geometry('300x300')

def num_add():

    prev_row = int(btn_list[-1].grid_info()['row'])
    add_btn = tk.Button(root,text='+',command=num_add)
    btn_list.append(add_btn)
    r1 = prev_row +1
    btn_list[-1].grid(row=r1,column=0)

    btn_list[-2].grid_forget()

btn_list = []
add_btn = tk.Button(root,text='+',command=num_add)
add_btn.grid(row=0,column=0)
btn_list.append(add_btn)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Since there is only one button, it will be shown at the top of the window no matters what `row` is.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually working as expected. If you look at the `.grid_info()` for the button after you click it, you will see that it says the button is on row 1, column 0. The reason it doesn't look as you'd expect is, that there is nothing in row 0 anymore so the row effectively has a height of 0.

Comment: I was confused by that phenomenon before. Thanks for explaining that to me!

Answer (score -1):

It this what you need?: i used place(x,y)

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('test1')
root.geometry('300x300')
global i
def num_add():
    global i
    add_btn.place_forget()
    i=i+1
    add_btn.place(x=2, y=i*30+20)

i=0   
add_btn = tk.Button(root,text='+',command=num_add)
add_btn.place(x=2, y=i*30+10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe I'll still stick to the "grid" method this time, but still thanks.